# В ответе на GET запрос получаю не полный HTML код

Tags: java, html, http, get

Пытаюсь получить HTML код со страницы своего приложения в Однокласстиках, в котором есть session_key. Но большого куска кода в котором он присутствует почему то в ответе нет. Не знаю в чем может быть проблема? При авторизации через браузер данный код присутствует.

```
public static HttpClient getThreadSafeClient(HttpClient client)  {

    client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    ClientConnectionManager mgr = client.getConnectionManager();
    HttpParams params = client.getParams();
    client = new DefaultHttpClient(new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params,

            mgr.getSchemeRegistry()), params);
    return client;
}

private static String getHtmlOK (){


    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    org.apache.http.client.CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
    HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext();
    context.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://www.ok.ru/https");

    List<org.apache.http.NameValuePair> nameValuePairList = new ArrayList<org.apache.http.NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("st.redirect", ""));
    nameValuePairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("st.asr", ""));
    nameValuePairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("st.posted", "set"));
    nameValuePairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("st.originalaction", "http://ok.ru/dk?cmd=AnonymLogin&st.cmd=anonymLogin"));
    nameValuePairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("st.fJS", "on"));
    nameValuePairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("st.st.screenSize", "1366 x 768"));
    nameValuePairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("st.st.browserSize", "628"));
    nameValuePairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("st.st.flashVer", "18.0.0"));
    nameValuePairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("st.email", "login"));
    nameValuePairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("st.password", "password"));
    nameValuePairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("st.iscode", "false"));

    BufferedReader br = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairList));
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, context);
        Header locetionHeader = response.getFirstHeader("location");


        httpClient = getThreadSafeClient(httpClient);

        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY) {
            // Выводим страницу на экран
            String locetion;
            if (locetionHeader != null){
                locetion = locetionHeader.getValue();
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(locetion);

                response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, context);

                httpGet = new HttpGet("http://ok.ru/game/1146333440");


                httpClient = getThreadSafeClient(httpClient);

                response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, context);

                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        response.getEntity().getContent()));

                while (((line = br.readLine()) != null)) {
                    sb.append(line);
                    sb.append(newline);
                }
            }


        } else {
            System.out.println("А страничка-то и не загрузилась!!!");
            System.out.println(locetionHeader.getValue());

        }
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("Проблемы со связью");
    }
System.out.println(sb);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Вероятно сервер слишком умный и как-то отличает ваш запрос от запроса из браузера. Может, по User-agent смотрит или ещё как. А через [API](https://apiok.ru/), как нормальные люди делают, не судьба?

Comment: @TagirValeev Не нашел как можно достать session_key через API, в самой документации сказано что нужно зайти на страницу приложение с включенным DOM-инспектором. Более вменяемого способа похоже нет.

Answer (score 1):

Очень часто вывод тормозят escape-символы, кавычки итд.
У меня было подобное. тормозил BOM.
Сравните коды, из браузера и в буфере, может в символ уперся.